# Using jq to suffix a string to a field in an object not containing it

Tags: jq

I have a json as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "batchPools": {
      "value": [
        {
          "networkConfiguration": {
            "subnetId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxxx/subnets/sample-name-batch",
            "subnetAddressPrefix": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "networkConfiguration": {
            "subnetId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxxx/subnets/sample-name",
            "subnetAddressPrefix": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to check if any of the `networkConfiguration.subnetID` under the array `value` contains the string `batch`. If yes then nothing needs to be done. Else, append `-batch` to the existing value. In this case, only the second `networkConfiguration.subnetID` of the array should be updated.

I tried the following:

`(.parameters.batchPools.value[] | select(.networkConfiguration.subnetId | contains("-batch") | not) | .networkConfiguration.subnetId) |= (.networkConfiguration.subnetId+"-batch")`

I get the following error:
`jq: error (at <stdin>:38): Cannot index string with string "networkConfiguration" exit status 5`

I tried this:

`(.parameters.batchPools.value[] | select(.networkConfiguration.subnetId | contains("batch") | not) | .networkConfiguration.subnetId) |= "someValue"`

This worked fine and replaced the entire `subnetId` with `someValue`. I am not able to figure out why the previous command is not working out. Please help.

Comment: You first command does not work because you apply twice the path `.networkConfiguration.subnetId` in cascade. You can either keep the one right after `select` or the one in the final concatenation filter, but not both. Note that you could simply use `(.parameters.batchPools.value[].networkConfiguration.subnetId | select(contains("batch") | not)) += "-batch"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is now working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the whole path of `subnetId` again. You've already selected that node from the pipeline before. Just use the `+=` append operator to suffix the required string

```
( .parameters.batchPools.value[] | 
  select(.networkConfiguration.subnetId | contains("batch") | not) | 
  .networkConfiguration.subnetId ) += "-batch"
```

<sup>[jqplay - Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1AxpZWUAcV)</sup>